# Rails Request Formatting as JS, Need Request to Look for Regular Rails Template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to render a bootstrap modal in a rails partial through the `#new` action using javascript (syntax is slim template, just cleaner erb).

```
= link_to 'ADD NEW', new_hiring_site_path, {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#hiring_site_modal"}}
```

This is the partial the `#new` action renders:

```
#hiring_site_modal.modal.fade tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        #hiring_site_modal_header.h4.modal-title
      .modal-body.address-section
        .form-group.hidden
          input type="hidden" id="hiring_site_id" name="hiring_site_id" value='0'
        .form-group
          label for='hiring_site_address_line_1' Address Line 1
          input.form-control.input-lg.address_line_1.required.input-length-long type="text" id='hiring_site_address_line_1' name='hiring_site_address_line_1'
...
```

This is my controller action:

```
def new
  @site = HiringSite.new({})

  respond_to do |f|
    f.html
  end
end
```

Now, when I submit a request like this, this is the response I get:

```
[Request Summary] {:method=>"GET", :path=>"/hiring_sites", :format=>:html, :controller=>"HiringSitesController", :action=>"index", :status=>200, :duration=>2083.21, :view=>1979.28, :db=>2.84, :application=>"enrollment-rails-app", :rails_env=>"development"
```

And when I change the route to format as html in the link helper:

```
= link_to 'ADD NEW', new_hiring_site_path(format: 'html'), {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#hiring_site_modal"}}
```

The client then ends up looking for a new.html file. Do you know how I get this to generate a default controller response of rendering a template?

Or maybe I should stick with golf.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, do you mean: "How do I get this to generate a default controller response of rendering a specific partial?" : `render partial: "partial_name"`

Comment: how do I get it to generate a response of looking for my template instead of looking for JS or .html

Comment: Your template (view partial) is written in HTML. What is the file name for it? I don't use slim personally, but some quick searching told me that your partial's name should be "partial_name.html.slim". You should have a gem that automatically converts slim files in to the appropriate HTML files at runtime (Rails comes with ERB support but you need to add Slim support via a gem). Meaning that Rails will look for, and find, "partial_name.html" at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

By rails convention, when you call a controller action, Rails will end it by automatically attempting to `render` a view template with the same name (located in the view folder with the same name as the controller). In your case, calling the `#new` controller action causes rails to attempt to `render` the `new.html` view template.

If you would like your controller action to `render` a different view template, do so with the `render "template_name"` function. If you would like your controller action to render a partial view template, do so with the `render partial: "partial_name"` function.

In your example, you'd like the `#new` action to render a specific partial so you'll want to end your `#new` action with `render partial: "partial_name"`

(And just to be clear--because you asked how to get Rails to render a template: `new.html` is a view template)

More information on using Rails' `render` function can be found in the "Layout and Rendering in Rails" Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render